# Core Data Object for ID Only Found Once

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've got a huge xml File which needs to be parsed.
For different Tags inside the xml, e.g Football Soccer Data, I create NSManagedObjects e.g. SoccerPlayer and so forth.

I also need to use these objects a few times within the parsing method and so I created an Object which finds me the right object for the id I provide.

This works fine for the first game inside the xml but won't work for any one after that.

Could be the problem that I have to delete a few objects as I parse through the xml?

For my XML Parsing Framework, I use TouchXML.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour before?

Comment: Clarification: Is the `id` the managed object id provided by the API or is it a custom id that you create? Is the "Object which finds me the right object for the id" a managed object? What does your data model look like? I think we need more detail to answer this question.

Comment: I think we need some code.  Depending on how you did it, ther is a chance that your object or dictionary or whatever is out of scope, deallocated, or replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that some code would help -- it's hard to understand exactly what the problem is. Nevertheless, I'll point out that the documentation for NSManagedObject's `-objectID` says:

> **Important:**  If the receiver has not yet been saved, the object ID is a
>   temporary value that will change when
>   the object is saved.

So, if you're creating an object, storing it's objectID, saving the context, and then trying to find the object with the objectID that you stored, you're probably going to fail because the temporary objectID was replaced with a permanent one when the context was saved.